# React&Redux: I have State in the background, but can't render the looped-through Array in my JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, mern

So far I have `GET_TOURNAMENTS` that sets all tournament objects in my state, and I render em on the page.

Then, I gave each tournament a button that calls `showTournament()` which selects whichever tournament I click, and updates the state.  When I click `SHOW_TOURNAMENT` my state looks like:

```
tournament
  tournaments: [{...}, {...}]           <<~~this is from GET_TOURNAMENTS
  showTournament: {                     <<~~begins as (showTournament: "") until showTournament() action
    _id: "etc",
    title: "Tournament One",
    status: "Open",
    participants: [                          <<~~an array of User objects
      0: {_id: "asdf", username: "asdf"},
      1: {_id: "asdf", username: "asdf"}
    ]
  }
```

Annnnnnnnd I've attempted to render all of this in my ShowTournament component by doing:

```
class TournamentShow extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        tournament: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };

    render() {
        const { _id, title, hostedBy, status, participants } = this.props.tournament.showTournament;

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{ title }</h1>
                <p>status: { status }</p>
                <p>Registered Participants:</p>
                {
                    participants ?
                    participants.forEach(participant => {
                        return (
                            <ul>
                                <li>{participant}</li>
                            </ul>
                        )
                    }) :
                    null
                }
                <p>Hosted by: { hostedBy }</p>
                <Link to="#">Sign Up</Link><br/>
                <Link to="/">Back to Tournaments main page</Link>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    tournament: state.tournament,
    auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { showTournament })(TournamentShow);
```

This shows nothing.  Nothing is rendered even if there are Participants in the array.

I also tried simply  <<~~ EDITED: I had the  tags inside at first, put them outside the {}

```
                <p>Registered Participants:</p>
                <ul>
                  {
                      participants.forEach(participant => {
                          return (
                              <li>{participant}</li>
                          )
                      })
                  }
                </ul>
```

to which I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`

All the non-array data from the `showTournament` renders just fine.. I have found other Stack Overflow questions and tried a number of solutions but other questions are just different enough that I can't figure out how to get the right implementation.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need yo use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ca/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objectes_globals/Array/map) to render an array, [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ca/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objectes_globals/Array/forEach) doesn't return anything to render, it just applies given function for each array item.

Then make sure you have the right data from a reducer, just set a `breakpoint` or use `console.log` to see thich data you are trying to render.

```
<ul>
  {
    participants.map(participant => (
      <li key={participant._id}>
        {participant.username}
      </li>
    ))
  }
</ul>
```

Comment: The rest of the showTournament's data is rendered fine.. and I tested it with multiple tournament objects.  I believe I'm getting the right data.

I just tried your solution even adding a unique key `participant[0]` and I tried `participant[0]._id` but i'm still getting the TypeError: cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: `TypeError: cannot read property 'map' of undefined` mean's that you don't have proper data to render, your `participants` property is undefined. Did you try to set a breakpoint or log it to the console to make sure?

Comment: Not entirely sure howt to set a breakpoint but console.log shows 
`
undefined
(2) [{...}, {...}]
` 

There are 2 participants so that makes sense.  But the first thing is 'undefined' ...

Comment: So you got this error because when render was called for the first times `participants` property was undefined. You can make sure that you will always have it, at least an empty array, or just use a condition `participants && participants.map(...)`. I strongly recommend the 1st option.

p.s. Use `debugger` keyword to set a breakpoint or you can do it from your browser developer console.

Comment: That worked!
{
  participants && participants.map(participant => (
    <li key={participant._id}>{participant.username}</li>
  ))
}

Comment: Glad to help you!

Answer (score 2):

1) You need to use `map` because `forEach` doesn't return anything so whatever you're returning in `forEach` isn't even visible to outside world of `forEach`. [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will return an array.

2) What are you trying to do by `{participant}`? It's an object, so either print it using `JSON.stringify(participant)` or better yet, print `_id` and `username` separately as shown below:

```
participants.map(participant => 
   (
      <ul>
         <li>{participant._id}</li>
         <li>{participant.username}</li>
      </ul>
   )
)
```

3) If you're getting an error as you say then it's likely that `participants` is `undefined`. Can you try debugging and see whether its values are populated or not. If debugging isn't possible, simply try printing it using

```
<div>{JSON.stringify(participants)}</div>
```

or even

```
<div>{JSON.stringify(this.props.tournament.showTournament)}</div>
```

Comment: To answer your initial question, i'm trying to merely render the list of participants on the page.

But yes! That makes perfect sense.  I was trying to render the Object in JSX instead of just their usernames. I tried your first solution but I'm still getting `undefined`

The third code you wrote actually rendered something on the screen.  I got the raw data at least.  Looks like

`Registered Fighters
[{"_id":"1234", "username":"Dustin", etc}, 
{"_id":"2345", "username":"Cintron", etc}]`

Comment: Third code was stringified `this.props.tournament.showTournament`, right?
From your output, it's clear that `participants` array doesn't exist inside `showTournament`.

Also, there should be something between `Registered Fighters` and `[{"_id":"1234",..`
The latter is an array. Its name (or key) is what you need, I think.  Can you paste keys as well (right now we only see values is my guess)?

Comment: Forgive me, I meant to say your SECOND code produced the raw data in the browser.  It showed the participants.  I also did the third, to see the showTournament itself and that renders the tournament data on the screen also.

Comment: I still don't understand what's `Registered Fighters` lol. Anyways, if you have the array then try these:
Minimise all the css / styling stuff as well as other values by directly returning
`<div>{participants[0].username}</div>`

In general, since you're able to print an object / array, you should be able to work your way inside that step by step e.g.
We know that `participants` is an array (as printed)
try `participants[0]` and then `participants[0].username`
use `JSON.stringify` to your advantage

Comment: Thank you.  This was a big help.  You and Nazar got me through it